# Solving difference equation by z transform

Tags: recurrence-relations, control-theory, z-transform

I have the following difference equation:

$$\ \  y(k+2) - 2y(k+1) +2y(k) = x(k) \,$$
where x(k) is an input of the form $\ x(k) = cos(\pi k)\ $, we also have the initial value conditions
$$\ y(0) = 1\,$$
$$\ y(1) = 1\,$$
I got to the following equation by applying the properties of time shifting:
$$\ Z^2Y[Z] - Z^2y(0) - Zy(1) - 2ZY[Z] + 2Zy(0) + 2Y[Z] = X[Z]\,$$
My goal was to get to a transfer function in order to analyze how the system behaves, but it doesn't seem like it's possible since the initial conditions are not zero. Are there other approaches to this problem? (P.S. It needs to be solved by Z transform)

Comment: But you know $y(0)$ and $y(1)$! Feeding them in, $(z^2 - 2z + 2)Y(z) = X(z) + z^2 + z \iff Y(z) = \frac{X(z)}{z^2 -2z +2} + \frac{3z - 2}{z^2 - 2z + 2} + 1$.

Now figure out $X(z)$, do the usual partial fraction decompositions, and appeal to the linearity of the generating functions.

Comment: Is $x(k) = \cos(\pi\omega)$ a typo? Presumably it should depend on $k$.

Comment: Yes, my apologies it should be k instead of omega. I'll edit it right away.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Yes, I can get to a pretty big expansion there. I was wondering if there was no way to actually isolate the output divided by input (Y/X) as to get a clean and nice to work with transfer function. If it is possible, we solve the problem in considerable less time.

Comment: Ah, but the transfer function construct implicitly only works for linear systems, and $(x,y)$ viewed as a system isn't linear. $y[kx](0) = 1$ regardless of $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the difference equation:

$$y(k+2) - 2y(k+1) +2y(k) = x(k)$$

We have:

$$
\begin{align}
x(k)&= \cos(\pi k) & y(0)&=1 & y(1)&=1\
\end{align}
$$

Z-transforming both sides of the equation:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{Z}\left[y(k+2) - 2y(k+1) +2y(k)\right]&=\mathcal{Z}\left[x(k)\right]\\
z^2Y(z) - z^2y(0) - zy(1) - 2zY(z) + 2zy(0) + 2Y(z) &= X(z)\\
Y(z)(z^2-2z+2)-z^2+z&=X(z)\\
\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}(z^2-2z+2)-\frac{(z^2-z)}{X(z)}&=1\\
\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}&=\frac{1}{(z^2-2z+2)}+\frac{(z^2-z)}{X(z)(z^2-2z+2)}
\end{align}
$$

Using a Z-transform table, we know that:

$$\mathcal{Z}[\cos(ak)]=\frac{z(z-\cos(a))}{z^2-2z\cos(a)+1}$$

Then:

$$X(z)=\mathcal{Z}[\cos(\pi k)]=\frac{(z^2+z)}{z^2+2z+1}$$

Substituting it back on the equation, we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}&=\frac{1}{(z^2-2z+2)}+\frac{z(z-1)(z^2+2z+1)}{z(z+1)(z^2-2z+2)}\\
&=\frac{(z+1)(z^2-2z+2)+(z-1)(z^2+2z+1)(z^2-2z+2)}{(z+1)(z^2-2z+2)^2}\\
&=\frac{(z+1)+(z-1)(z^2+2z+1)}{(z+1)(z^2-2z+2)}\\
&=\frac{z+1+z^3+2z^2+z-z^2-2z-1}{(z+1)(z^2-2z+2)}\\
&=\frac{z^2(z+1)}{(z+1)(z^2-2z+2)}\\
&=\frac{z^2}{(z^2-2z+2)}
\end{align}
$$

If what I did is correct, this is an unstable system, once we have Zeros:$\{0,0\}$
Poles:$\{1\pm j\}$